# Follow the link including the input value using two input and button tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

How to follow a link with a value in the input field without writing additional javascript, i.e. all code in html input and button tags?

Let's say there is a Google site for search and the search line is in input, so that when you click on the button, the link `https://www.google.com/search?q=` and the value of the input field, for example, `text` are substituted:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=text

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="text">
<button onclick="code">Follow a search link with a value in input</button>
```

Comment: You can't do this unless you use js or form tag

Comment: No, but I thought you could put js code in onclick for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It’s necessary without using a form, you can have js code"
Well, there is a js code that you can use to achieve this

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="text">
<button onclick="search()">Follow a search link with a value in input</button>
<script>
    function search() {
        const searchValue = document.getElementById('search').value

        window.location.href = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${ searchValue }`
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going attach an event handler at least do it unobtrusively. Inline event handlers are bad practice and should be avoided. I'm also confused how this is the accepted answer when the question asks for no JS.

Comment: "Inline event handlers are bad practice and should be avoided" you're right but in her post, he have already an `onclick` attribut. "... the question asks for no JS" he said it in all her comment that "It’s necessary without using a form, you can have js code" :)

Comment: The point is you don't need JS for this. Just adding it for the sake of adding it is not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

To do this without any JS you simply need to create a `<form>` element whose target is `google.com/search`.

The only things to note is that the `action` should be `get` and the `input` name needs to be `q` so that the correct querystring format is used when the form is submit. Try this:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="q" value="" required />
  <button type="submit">Follow a search link with a value in input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It’s necessary without using a form, you can have js code

Comment: Well yes, but your question is asking how to avoid writing JS...?

Comment: No, but I thought you could put js code in onclick for the button

Comment: While that's possible it's still using JS. It's also bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

1. Form action should be set to the website you need, google in this case
2. Form method should be `GET`
3. Form fields must be named, like the parameters in the query string

Example:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="serach"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It’s necessary without using a form, you can have js code